# Updating a collection with a query that specifies sort and limit

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an email notification collection that will be accessed by multiple threads. I need to lock some records by the current thread so I can work with them exclusively.

My collection looks like this:

```
public class EmailNotification
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public string LockedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LockedUntil { get; set; }

    public int Priority { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

My idea was to "soft-lock" the records by updating the "LockedBy" and "LockedUntil" fields first (and therefore take advantage of mongoDB update locking) and on a second step retrieve the records I already soft-locked and work with them.

I am having trouble with the first step. I need to lock the "N most pressing emails" with an update command. This means I need to find all records that have the "LockedUntil" field either set to null or to a value in the past, sort them by "Priority" (desc) and then by "CreatedAt" (asc), and update only the top N records that result from this **in one single command** in order to achieve the soft lock without running into concurrency issues.

I am trying to do this from a C# method, so using the CSharp driver is a must. Is there a way to accomplish what I need with the latest version of the driver (2.6)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update multiple documents in a single, atomic update
command:

> In MongoDB, write operations, e.g. db.collection.update(),
>   db.collection.findAndModify(), db.collection.remove(), are atomic on
>   the level of a single document. For fields that must be updated
>   together, embedding the fields within the same document ensures that
>   the fields can be updated atomically.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-data-for-atomic-operations/

If you attempt to do implement this lock pattern you run the risk of the update command yielding to another process/thread before all of them are updated.

you could instead use a findandmodify call to lock and retrieve documents one at a time, in a loop.

> **FindAndModify Method**
>
> Use FindAndModify when you want to find a matching document and update
>   it in one atomic operation. FindAndModify always updates a single
>   document, and you can combine a query that matches multiple documents
>   with a sort criteria that will determine exactly which matching
>   document is updated. In addition, FindAndModify will return the
>   matching document (either as it was before the update or after) and if
>   you wish you can specify which fields of the matching document to
>   return.

findAndModify is available via the C# driver and it's use is covered here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/

Comment: I figured that would be the case, but I was hoping for an easy alternative. I did find the FindAndModify useful for my purposes, though. Thank you!